# ASP.NET Identity Claims and Logins

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, claims-based-identity, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to understand new Identity auth.
Could anyone tell me, why should i use UserClaims and UserLogins? (i don't use any external auth). Where should i use it?

How to sign in without claims? Currently i'm signing in with claims:

```
var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
Authentication.SignIn(identity);
```

Answer (score -1):

Asp.Net Identity is development of claims idea from Windows Identity Foundation. So you can google it for more information.
More about claims concept itself you can learn from [here](http://claimsid.codeplex.com/). (look for "Guide on wiki" chapter with links on topics)